# Airflow tasks are getting marked as success, even though it has not yet started

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using Airflow 1.10.3. Currently, seeing a lot of tasks are marked as "success", but start date, end date and duration are empty for such tasks. There are no logs for those tasks.

[image: airflow-success-task-instances]

It doesn't raise any pager or anything currently and we are seeing increased silent failures day by day.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the DAG configuration + code?

Comment: You should bump to a more recent version of Airflow as well

Comment: @ryw is this a problem with the scheduler?